# API Version Incompatibilities

Tags: android

**API Version Incompatibilities**

I have made an app using android studio, until now I have been testing it on a 'Nexus 5X (API 23) emulator'.  However, today i started debugging the app on a 'Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (API 18)' and the app will not even start.  I know this is because of incompatibilities between the API's specifically something to do with the Theme i'm using.  What i want to know is how i can fix this problem without changing the look of the app drastically.

**Log Cat Crash Log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.***.********/com.***.********.MenuActivity}:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
at com.***.*******.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".About" />
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".********Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".********Activity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name=".*******Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

**Gradle Build App File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***.*******"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

**Note:** The last two lines (the ones with compile...) are underlined in red and say 'This support library should not use a different version(22) than the compile SDK version(21).'

**Edit:** If I change the Theme for the main activity to '@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar' the application will start however, the look of the application changes.  Also, other activities that do not use the new theme work fine.

Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: The error is there and clear in the stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: That fixed it but then caused another crash to do with there being to action bar i then fixed that and now it works.